# Bot framework-Adaptive card-Unable to get data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, botframework, chatbot, adaptive-cards

I'm new to bot framework and learning. Here I'm looking for a solution I'm facing in Adaptive card that I using for my chatbot. I learn that we can design that adaptive card as per our need using adaptivecards.io/designer where we get the card as json code.

so here is my json code for adaptive card

```
     {
 "type": "AdaptiveCard",
 "$schema": 
 "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptivecard.json",
 "version": "1.2",
 "msTeams": {
 "width": "full"
 },
 "body": [
 {
  "type": "TextBlock",
  "text": "Adaptive Card Example",
  "wrap": true,
  "size": "large",
  "weight": "bolder",
  "id": "title"
 },
 {
  "type": "Input.Text",
  "placeholder": "Provide your thoughts",
  "separator": true,
  "isMultiline": true,
  "id": "thoughts"
 },
 {
  "type": "ActionSet",
  "separator": true,
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Submit",
      "style": "positive",
      "id": "submit"
    }
  ]
 }
 ]
}
```

> so when I run my bot and see the output in emulator, I can see the adaptive card
> [adaptive card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YK93V.png)
> when i give the input and click the submit button it showing the error as **System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Please explain in detail to resolve this

Comment: Have you tried checking out the [Using adaptive cards](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/07.using-adaptive-cards) sample?

Comment: Hi, is there any update about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I used the same Adaptive card & worked fine
Read value from the adaptive card use the value property **${turn.activity.value}**

Comment: this is what I was trying to do in my case `Input.Date`.  Im saving this to user.period (as per my variable name) then I wanted to display this to user asking to confirm.  But it is not rendering..

Comment: What is a issue?

Comment: Hey Vinoth, I finally figured it out.  The issue was I wasnt seeing the the value printed on the chat.  I checked the composer logs, and I saw that it was there during post and I was setting the user.date (in my case) before that post.  Moving the set property outside of the attachement activity allowed me to capture it.

Comment: that's great Gel